# ¿Como crear un campo solo TIME con php Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, api, datetime

Estoy creando un API con php laravel y MySql; y estoy creando migraciones y seeders. Tengo esta tabla:

```
Schema::create('schedules', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->engine='InnoDB';
        $table->increments('schedule_id');
        $table->date('time_to_open'); //<----- esta
        $table->date('time_to_close'); //<----- y esta
        $table->boolean('is_active');
        $table->string('created_by');
        $table->timestamps();
                
});
```

Y tengo dos campos `time_to_open` y `time_to_close`, en esos solo me interesa guandar una hora ejemplo: `22:00` o `14:30` o `07:40` pero no se como poner esos campos solo TIME pues al dejarlos DateTime o Date me trae la informacion de las fechas y eso no me interesa aqui.

y poder cargar el dato desde un seeder.

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar

```
$table->time('time_to_open', $precision = 0);
```

Eso crea una columna de tipo tiempo, también hay un tipo timeTz si deseas utilizarlo con zona horaria

La documentación completa está [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-time)

Comment: re bien esa era la solución gracias. lo unico que ya queda es en el seeder cargarla como: time_to_open = '20:52'